# Best design for two different tables with 90% same columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I have a `feature_values` table which contains data stored by users: they can edit and update this table.

```
user_feature_values
user  | year  |  quarter | gdp | other 
---------------------------------------
1       2018      Q1        1.5    1.2
1       2018      Q2        1.6    1.5
5       2017      Q1       -1.2    1.0
.......................................
.............
4       2017      Q4        1.0    2.5
```

There is another similar table that stores default values. Users can't edit this.

```
default_feature_values
country  | year  |  quarter  | gdp  | other 
---------------------------------------
5          2018      Q1        1.8    2.0
10         2015      Q2        1.4    1.2
120        2017      Q3       -1.2    1.0
.......................................
.............
115        2016      Q4        1.5    2.15
```

Current scenario: 
Once the user is created, I am literally copying the default values into `user_feature_values` based on the user's country. So that they can edit the default values in their table with their own values. At a later time, they can opt for default values; which are copied to `user_feature_values` table from `default_feature_values` table.

Is this a bad design?

How well this can be implemented?

Comment: Naming tables with a `#` as the first character seems like a poor choice (although I can't really explain why I have this bias).  That said, I can't figure out what the question is asking.  Is it asking for an *opinion* on a design?  Or is it asking for a way to implement functionality.  The first suggests closing for one reason; the second for another.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No. I haven't named them that way. I just used `#` to differentiate between a table and actual feature_values to explain the scenario. I'm asking for an opinion on the design and whether this can be implemented in a better way.

Comment: . . And "opinion-based" is the fifth close reason for closing a question (which I assume you know, based on your points).  You can phrase a similar question differently -- based on performance, for instance.  I would say that this design has a gap -- users may want to "remember" their values and go back to them, but your design doesn't support this.

Comment: to add to @GordonLinoff 's comment this is "opinion-based" i very much agree on that,,, At first seight how the data looks like and what you said i would mostly likely go for one table `feature_values` (with default column values) and a `feature_values_permission` table with `feature_values` id's  which the user could edit and which ones not....

Comment: Can a user be in multiple countries?  Of so, won't the `user...` table need a `country` column?

Comment: @RickJames, yes the `user` table has a `country` column. With my current approach, once the user is created, the default feature values for that country are copied to user's feature values table; which he can edit/update later.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution for SQL server but i guess this way With a little change work well for mysql (i don't have any idea about mysql):

step1: create linked server like this query (or set other way in object explorer):

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin     @rmtsrvname=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'DBuserName(like sa)',@rmtpassword='########'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SetMainDBaddressHERE', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

step2: use information_schema.columns for compare and alter command like this:

```
with t as(
    select TABLE_NAME,column_name,s.DATA_TYPE,s.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
            case    when TABLE_NAME like 'vw_%' then N'Alter view as other DB'
                    when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null and s.DATA_TYPE in ('image','datetime') then 'Alter table '+TABLE_NAME+' add '+column_name+' '+s.DATA_TYPE
                    when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is null then 'Alter table '+TABLE_NAME+' add '+column_name+' '+s.DATA_TYPE +' null' 
            else  'Alter table '+TABLE_NAME+' add '+column_name+' '+s.DATA_TYPE +'('+convert(nvarchar,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)+')'
            end as Command
    from [MainServerDBadress].DBname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS s where TABLE_NAME like 'vw_%' or  TABLE_NAME like 'tbl_%'
    )
Select TABLE_NAME,column_name,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH , Command
from t 
where  TABLE_NAME+column_name not in ( select TABLE_NAME+column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like 'vw_%' or  TABLE_NAME like 'tbl_%')
order by 1,2
```

I use alter command for table.
I use 'vw_' for all view and 'tbl_tablename' for all table. if you don't have this model you can delete some code for above query.

Hopefully someone will upgrade this SQL-database solution to mysql.

Comment: SQL tag on this website is not meant for SQL Server SQL dialect it is meant for valid ANSI/ISO Structured Query Language (SQL) specification language code, also as the MySQL tag is tagged the answer should have MySQL valid syntax... This provided code will not run on MySQL..